# How to put a graphic in landscape mode but make the rest of the text continuous?

Tags: graphics, landscape

When I put something in the landscape environment, the paragraphs written before and after are separated in different pages (page n=paragraph that barely fills the page, page n+1=landscape, page n+2=paragraph...)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You should take a look at the `rotating` package.

Comment: You should really elaborate what you're asking.  A MWE would help.  Also, what does this have to do with biblatex?